# putting my rails code onto heroku in a branch

Tags: git, heroku

I'm developing my web application and testing it afterward uploading to Heroku.
I don't want to merge this branch with the master branch yet due to a testing purpose.

My question here is: would it be possible to put my code to a branch other than the master branch?

and if so, how can I access it through an URL to my heroku newly created branch?

or should I consider using git-flow, as I found many people use it on this purpose based on my research?

any advice?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Heroku only launches code on its own `master` branch. You can push any local branch to Heroku's remote master via `git push heroku branchname:master` (where `branchname` is the local name of the branch you want to push).

Comment: I have done this several times and it works fine.